# NopCommerce Shipping Providers Table

Tags: nopcommerce

On this page "/Admin/Shipping/Providers" I see Australia Post, Canada Post, FedEx, etc and one default active "Fixed Rate Shipping".

Where can you find the table that stores the shipping providers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

List of shipping provider is not stored intp database (table). They are plugins. You can find them into \Plugins directory.

But some shipping providers (plugins) store some data into table.